# Create XML document with namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to generate an XML document like the one below. I tried several solution but when I add the namespace, I have the namespace almost everywhere
like

```
<FieldB xlmns="">BBBBB</FieldB>
```

Do you have an idea how to get this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<value attributeA="A" attributeB="B" xmlns:XXX="http://MyURLA" xmlns="http://MyURLB">
    <FieldA>AAAAA</FieldA>
    <FieldB>BBBBB</FieldB>
    <FieldB>BBBBB</FieldB>
    <status attributeC="C">
        <FieldC>ValueFieldC</FieldC>
    </status>
    <LastUpdate date="2011-02-11T10:00:56.350" login="testing"/>
    <XXX:Infos>
        <XXX:Info>
            <XXX:InfoA>false</XXX:InfoA>
            <XXX:InfoB>false</XXX:InfoB>
        </XXX:Info>
    </XXX:Infos>
</value>
```

Comment: You haven't shown us any code, which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: Your XML is invalid, `standalone` needs to be either `yes` or `no`

Comment: Does `xlmns=""` even qualify as a namespace?

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right Jon, next time I'll do it. It's because I tried several solution and I don't know the most "correct"

Comment: @Kris-I: Why aren't you editing your question to show it this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a XNamespace:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XNamespace nsA = "http://MyURLA";
        XNamespace nsB = "http://MyURLB";
        var doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement(
                nsB + "value",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "XXXX", nsA),
                new XAttribute("attributeA", "A"),
                new XAttribute("attributeB", "B"),
                new XElement("FieldA", "AAAA"),
                new XElement("FieldA", "BBBB"),
                new XElement("FieldC", "CCCC"),
                new XElement(
                    "status", 
                    new XAttribute("attributeC", "C"),
                    new XElement("FieldC", "ValueFieldC")
                ),
                new XElement(
                    "LastUpdate", 
                    new XAttribute("date", DateTime.Now), 
                    new XAttribute("login", "testing")
                ),
                new XElement(
                    nsA + "Infos",
                    new XElement(nsA + "InfoA", false),
                    new XElement(nsA + "InfoB", false)
                )
            )
        );
        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's almost correct @Darin but there is exactly the same problem than my tests there are an xmlns="" as attribute in each node

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you're not putting `FieldA`, `FieldB` etc in the right namespace - you don't want to have an explicit namespace declaration in the XML, but the XML you've shown will actually have them in the namespace with URL `http://MyURLB`, due to the way defaults are inherited.

I suspect if you just use:

```
XNamespace nsB = "http://MyURLB";

var doc = ... {
    new XElement(nsB + "value", 
        ...
        new XElement(nsB + "FieldA", "AAAA");
        new XElement(nsB + "FieldB", "BBBB");
        new XElement(nsB + "FieldC", "CCCC");
        ...
    )
};
```

then it'll be fine. The `FieldA` (etc) elements won't have an explicit namespace reference, because they're in the same namespace as their parent element.